# .NET 4.0 throwing a TypeInitialization Exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

After installing .NET 4.0, I am now getting an exception on this statement:

```
 if (mainForm.versionNumber.Contains("BETA"))
```

This is how  versionNumber is defined:

```
public static string versionNumber = "1.1.1 " + compileDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

and the run-time errorr is "TypeInitializationException".  What changed from .NET v3.5  to 4.0 that would cause this?  And how do I fix it?

UPDATE:  here is the exception detail:

```
> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled   Message=The type
> initializer for 'Media_Inventory_Manager.mainForm' threw an exception.
> Source=PragerMediaInventoryManager  
> TypeName=Media_Inventory_Manager.mainForm   StackTrace:
>        at Media_Inventory_Manager.Prager.Main() in D:\Prager Software\Media Inventory Manager\Program.cs:line 36
>        at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>        at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.FormatException
>        Message=The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0.
>        Source=mscorlib
>        StackTrace:
>             at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
>             at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
>             at Media_Inventory_Manager.mainForm..cctor() in D:\Prager Software\Media Inventory Manager\Main Form.cs:line 38
>        InnerException:
```

Comment: Might want to add the whole exception detail.

Comment: yeah, what's the inner exception?

Comment: How do I get the "inner exception?

Comment: @spokane-dude: look at exception's property `InnerException`.

Comment: ex.Message = "TypeInitializationException" -> ex.InnerException.Message = "???"

Comment: You can see from your detail: static constructor for `Media_Inventory_Manager.mainForm` failed trying to parse a string with `DateTime.Parse`. Because its argument was not a string. Could you please paste here your line 38?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is something wrong with a class initializer fails to initialize a type. It really hard to see what happens when you are not show that much code. If you read on mdsn it says:

> When a class initializer fails to initialize a type, a
>   TypeInitializationException is created and passed a reference to the
>   exception thrown by the type's class initializer. The InnerException
>   property of TypeInitializationException holds the underlying
>   exception.
>
> TypeInitializationException uses the HRESULT COR_E_TYPEINITIALIZATION,
>   that has the value 0x80131534.
>
> For a list of initial property values for an instance of
>   TypeInitializationException, see the TypeInitializationException
>   constructors.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx)

So knowing that i would look at the `InnerException` and see whats going on.

**EDIT**

With out knowing more about your code. This could be a way to get the `InnerException`

```
try
{
    mainForm.versionNumber.Contains("BETA");
}
catch(TypeInitializationException ex)
{
    var inner= ex.InnerException;
}
```

Comment: Failure in class initializer usually means that some exception was thrown when initializing some static fields or executing static constructor. Looking at `InnerException` must be helpful.

Comment: Yeah I would except that as well. That is why the OP need to supply us with the `InnerException`.

Comment: I found it!  the compileDate had garbage in the month (Mara)... thanks everybody... I really, really appreciate it.